# Set transparency of the legend background in a plot

Tags: plotting, legending, opacity

It is known that the instruction `LegendFunction` can be used to set the background color of the legend in a `Plot` or `ListPlot`, e.g.,

```
ListPlot[Range[0, 10], Joined -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[PointLegend[{"Title"}, LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> White] &)], {Right, Top}]
]
```

[image: Result of the plot]

However, I haven't found a way to set the transparency (or opacity) of the background. If I don't specify any background color, then the legend is overlapped by the plots; if I set it to, say, white as in the example above, then the legend covers the curves I'm plotting. Is there anything in between?

Comment: Change the background to `Background -> Opacity[0, White]` However, presumably the location of the legend was chosen to demonstrate whether the background was transparent rather than the final desired location.

Comment: Yeah sure, in this example I could have simply moved the legend elsewhere, but in other cases it wouldn't help, as I have curves everywhere in the plot. Anyway it works, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [`Transparent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transparent.html) directly as the most idiomatic short alternative, but you can also use [`Opacity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) as suggested by @BobHanlon in the comments.

```
ListPlot[
    Range[0, 10]
    , Joined -> True
    , PlotTheme->"Scientific"
    , PlotLegends -> Placed[
        PointLegend[
            {"Title"}
            , LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> Transparent] &)
        ]
        , {Right, Top}
    ]
]
```

[image]